# Delete file on process termination

Tags: winapi

Is there a way to create/access a temporary file (e.g. `GetTempFileName`) and delete it right after the process has been killed/terminated? I know it is possible with the JobAPI to terminate all child processes but I was wondering if you could use such a method with a file.

Comment: @DevSolar As far as I see `atexit()`, it won't run on the process' termination

Comment: @DevSolar: There is no SIGINT or SIGTERM on Windows. This is fairly unrelated. Anyway, David Heffernan already posted the correct answer, that works, regardless of how a process is terminated.

Comment: @DevSolar: *signal.h* allows developers to port code that relies on signals. It does not magically introduce signals into Windows. This is purely a software implementation, attempting to meet ANSI compatibility (SIGILL and SIGTERM are not generated on Windows, for example, neither is SIGINT). Do I want to reconsider my statement? Considering that the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) agrees with me, I don't have much of an incentive, now do I?

Comment: @IInspectable: Again I am stumped by Microsoft's failures to properly support standards. Retracting my comments.

Comment: @DevSolar: The documentation is publicly available. I don't think Microsoft is to blame for anything here.

Comment: @DevSolar Windows does not purport to support POSIX, or whatever standard you feel it should support.

Comment: @IInspectable: *minor* quibble, for the record - SIGINT is in fact emulated by the Microsoft C runtime (but only for console applications).  It isn't supported, but last time I checked at least the emulation was still in place.  If you register a SIGINT handler, it will run when control-C is pressed.  (The reason it isn't supported is that it runs in the "wrong" thread, violating the expectations of UNIX programmers.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That's what I loosely described as a *"software implementation"*. Thanks for the additional insight, nonetheless. It's useful, as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag to [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) and the file will be deleted when all of its handles are closed. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) says:

> The file is to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, which includes the specified handle and any other open or duplicated handles.

Comment: So does this guarantee the deletion at least on the next startup?

Comment: Startup? No, it will be deleted when all of the handles are closed. Assuming you don't duplicate them and pass them to other processes, all the handles will be closed when the process terminates.

Comment: I was talking about loss of power

Comment: I don't know how that is handled.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss: Power outages cannot be *handled*. They are an Act of God, as far as the application and operating system are concerned. There's nothing they can do about. If you are running mission critical software, implement redundancy. If you are concerned about confidential information leaking, encrypt the temporary file. If you merely want to keep a clean system, write an application, that performs the cleanup for you on every restart/login/whichever event you choose.

Comment: @IInspectable - [Obligatory Link](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/My-Tales) (specifically the 'Finally' section)

Comment: Technically, you can add a `RunOnce` startup item to clean up in case of loss of power and whatnot.